# Python Twisted Stopping The Reactor With Multiple Clients

Tags: python, client-server, twisted, reactor

If I create multiple clients by doing this:

```
def main():
    clients = [None]*10

    for i in range(0, 10):
        clients[i] = ClientFactory()
        reactor.connectTCP('192.168.0.1', 8000, clients[i])

    reactor.run()
```

How to I -gracefully- stop the reactor?  If I do:

```
self.transport.loseconnection()
```

In the protocol, then do:

```
reactor.stop()
```

In the factory, then the next client is going to try to come along a stop the reactor again.  However, this of course leads to the error:

```
Can't stop a reactor that isn't running
```

How can I gracefully stop the reactor in such a scenario?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take your reactor-management code out of your protocol implementation.  Replace it with some event-notification code that you can use to learn when the connection has done everything it needs to do.  For example, fire a `Deferred`.

Then wait on all the deferreds and stop the reactor when they're all done.  You might find [`gatherResults`](http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/api/twisted.internet.defer.gatherResults.html) helpful for this.

Answer (score 0):

It's been a while since I did anything with Twisted, but couldn't you just check the value of the `reactor.running` property first? E.g.,

```
# Gracefully stop the reactor
if reactor.running:
    reactor.stop()
```

Comment: This isn't ideal.  `running` doesn't mean what you think it does, so this solution will still fail sometimes.